# Changing legend labels for frequency polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble changing the labels on a frequency polygon.

When I do so on a histogram, it looks like this:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(value, fill=df$variable))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10, position=position_dodge(width=7), col="black") +
  labs(title="Exam Scores", x="Exam Score", y="Frequency") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Exam", labels = c("Exam 1", "Exam 2"))
```

And it yields this output:
[image: Side by side Histogram]

The same works for a boxplot.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_boxplot(col="black")+labs(title="Exam Scores", x="Exam Score") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Exam", labels = c("Exam 1", "Exam 2")) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: Boxplot]

However, when I make a Frequency Polygon, the legend labels do not change.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(value, fill=variable, color=variable)) +
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth=10) +
  labs(title="Exam Scores", x="Exam Score", y="Frequency") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Exam", labels = c("Exam 1", "Exam 2"))
```

[image: Frequency polygon]

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: ... try with `scale_color_discrete` instead of `scale_fill_discrete`. `geom_freqpoly` has no fill aes.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Can you post that as an answer so that I can give you the proper internet points :)

Comment: Everything fine. Always glad to help. Best S.